# Window Leak Error on pressing the back button in Media player app with media controls

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I have implemented media player controllers. The problem is that on moving from media player activity where user controls are visible to previous activity, the Window leak error occurs. Moreover back button is also become disable on adding media controllers.error occurs at this line 70 at  bestAudioController.show();

```
 public void playAudio() {

    bestService.playSong();

   bestAudioController.show();

}
```

and this line playAudio()

```
   private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder 
             iBinder) {
        Log.e("onServiceConnected,","MAINACTIVITY");
        bestService = ((BestService.MyBinder) iBinder).getService();
        isBound = true;

         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
          registerReceiver(onPrepareReceiver,      
                new IntentFilter("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED"));

      playAudio();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        Log.e("onServiceDisconnected","MAINACTIVITY");
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

The erro log shows the following

```
 Activity com.example.hawk.hojaa.PlayerActivity has leaked window 
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52a3f974 V.E.....
 R.....ID 0,0-768,176} that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.hawk.hojaa.PlayerActivity   
   has leaked window 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52a3f974 V.E.....  
R.....ID 0,0-768,176} that was originally added here        
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
        at 
        android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.
                                      addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:346)
        at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:306)
        at com.example.hawk.aise.PlayerActivity.
                                        playAudio(PlayerActivity.java:84)
        at com.example.hawk.aise.
                 PlayerActivity$1.onServiceConnected(PlayerActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.
                LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1106)
        at android.app.
          LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1123)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.
                               run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call `hide()` on the Dialog you created before exiting the Activity, e.g. in `onPause()` or `onDestory()`. All Windows&Dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.

You have to dismiss `bestAudioController` dialog when you switch to another activity.

Call `hide()` on the bestAudioController you created in before exiting your Activity, e.g. in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
         if (bestAudioController != null && bestAudioController.isShowing()) {
             bestAudioController.hide();
         }
         super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (bestAudioController != null && bestAudioController.isShowing()) {
            bestAudioController.hide();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

The `finish()` method will close the Activity, but the `bestAudioController` is still displaying!

**EDIT:**

If Dialog is `AlertDialog` then you should call `dismiss()`. and if it is `MediaController` dialog the you have to call `hide()`

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.How can i call dismiss method on bestAudioController. bestAudioController  object comes from a class that extends from MediaControl   public class BestAudioController extends MediaController {

    public BestAudioController(Context c){
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide(){

    }

}

Comment: did you try calling: bestAudioController.dismiss();

Comment: @Abad I have updated my answer. please try again with updated code

Comment: Yes on adding  bestAudioController.dismiss(); the dismiss turn into error.

Comment: try hide() instead of dismiss()

Comment: from which package you have imported MediaController?

Comment: android.widget.MediaController

Comment: here is link of developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html MediaController. you can see hide() method in that link. so you have to try and check application crashes or not?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used to resolve the issue was to call `dismiss()` on the dialog before `hide()` to ensure the dialog is completely removed before going to another activity.

```
 ...
 progressDialog.dismiss();
 progressDialog.hide();
 ...
```